# Braced-init-list and overloaded equality operator

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I would like to overload the equals operator to test one of my list classes, like such:

```
assert(L1 == {2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10});
```

As far as I understand point five of this list, I should be able to use braced-init-lists as the argument to a function:

> [5) in a function call expression, with braced-init-list used as an argument](http://acm2014.cct.lsu.edu/localdoc/cppreference/en/cpp/language/list_initialization.html)

So my question is, does operator overload count as a "function-call expression" and is there a way to get the syntax and semantics I want?

Right now I am getting the error:

```
initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator '=='
```

I can get it to work if I phrase it like this, but that's not what I want:

```
assert(L1 == List({2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10});
```

Comment: You could try it out...

Comment: @cad as far as I can see, he already tried it out and in his partial (?) humanoid implementation of the Standard he came to the conclusion that it should work.